# Non-consumable IAP receipt verification

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have one non-consumable IAP in iOS app (premium update) currently purchase ad restore are performed without receipt verification , i come along some articles that say that an IAP can be hacked in a jailbroken devices ,and i need to avoid this issue so

1- Should I call this verify method every time the user opens the app [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit)

```
let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .production, sharedSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator, forceRefresh: true) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let receipt):
        print("success: \(receipt)")
    case .error(let error):
        print("Verify receipt failed: \(error)")
    }
}
```

To make sure app is truly paid and IAP not hacked ?

2- Also inside the success block i should open the app premium features , while inside failure i should lock them ?